# Manually update Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I would like to switch to Alpha channel in Xamarin Studio on Windows, the Update utility managed to download GTK# and Xamarin Studio 6.1.0 but failed to download Xamarin 4.2.0 and couldn't resume the download.

My question is where the temporary files are stored? and can I get a direct link to the latest alpha Xamarin 4.2 to download it and put in in the temp folder.
A third question is can I install 4.2 with XS while continuing with 4.0 on VS?

Edit: I get the path:`C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\XamarinStudio-5.0\Cache\TempDownload`but I want to know to resume a failed download or get the direct link because I can only find those of stable releases.

Comment: @JamesMoore What do you mean it died? There is XS 6.0 and 6.1 for Windows alpha, did they announce something recently?

Comment: I think I'm reporting rumors as facts; I can't find a formal announcement.  Removing my comment.